# getting the Gradle error while runing the code as npx react-native run-android

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

D:\friends\ranees\MusicUi>npx react-native run-android
info Starting JS server...

- daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
- daemon started successfully
  info Launching emulator...
  error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: It took too long to start and connect with Android emulator: Pixel_6_Pro_API_33. You can try starting the emulator manually from the terminal with: C:\Users\kutta\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/emulator/emulator @Pixel_6_Pro_API_33.
  warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
  ^C^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? y

D:\friends\ranees\MusicUi>npx react-native run-android
info JS server already running.

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'D:\friends\ranees\MusicUi\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\kutta.gradle\caches\8.0.1\scripts\aryfjkmuz0zd77wq079pfevm4).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 64

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat tasks FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'D:\friends\ranees\MusicUi\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\kutta.gradle\caches\8.0.1\scripts\aryfjkmuz0zd77wq079pfevm4). > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 64 * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 4s.

I made a new app from react native and by runing the default file I get this error can't even run the default app in react native used android studio to make emulator

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

one way is to launch it manually using the command line or cmd type:

```
cd C:\Users\<YourUserName>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator>
```

and then:

```
.\emulator -avd Your_Emulator_Name -wipe-data
```